# .htaccess to match anything containing a character

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am trying to write a rule to skip over a fake directory with .htaccess. I have achieved this like

```
RewriteRule ^fake/(.+)$ /$1 [N,NC]
```

so now /fake/real would just get /real

But I have a need to target anything which is in the format xx-xx like en-gb or en-us

I have tried something like

```
RewriteRule ^a{5}/(.+)$ /$1 [N,NC]
```

which should try and match anything of length 5. But this does not work, and is only half the job anyway. How can I match anything like xx-xx ?

Comment: E.g. `[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}` would match lowercase letters two times, a dash and then two lowercase letters again.

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `a{5}`, it means match the character `a` **five times**.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

You want to match 2 alphabets, followed by a `-` and again 2 alphabets:

```
[a-z]{2}\-[a-z]{2}
```

The `[NC]` flag will take care of `EN-gb` or `eN-gB` etc. too.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, use:

```
[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}
```